# How can I edit the values in a intermediate ManyToMany table from the Django Admin site?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-admin, many-to-many

I want to be able to create cocktails in my database through the Django Admin site. For that I have a 'Cocktail' model and a 'Ingredient' model. They need a ManyToMany relation that allows for the additional field 'amount_in_oz', so I use a 'IngredientAmount' intermediate model with 'through'. In the admin site, when I click on 'Add Cocktail', I want to be able to name the cocktail and then add several items from the 'Ingredient' model whilst also specifying the 'amount_in_oz' for each.

```
# models.py----------------------------------------------------
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    alcoholic = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cocktail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    garnish = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    recipe = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='IngredientAmount')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class IngredientAmount(models.Model):
    cocktail = models.ForeignKey(Cocktail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredients = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_in_oz = models.FloatField(null=False)

    def __float__(self):
        return self.amount_in_oz

# admin.py-----------------------------------------------------
class CocktailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (('name', 'garnish'), )
    filter_horizontal = ('recipe', )  # Ideally, this line would have allowed it.

admin.site.register(Ingredient)
admin.site.register(Cocktail, CocktailAdmin)
```

It seems that because the intermediate table requires additional input, the filter_horizontal widget can't handle it.

I'm wondering it the best way to accomplish this is to create a custom Form or custom validation? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

Or make use of formfield_overides?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides

Or create a new widget for ModelAdmin, something like 'filter_horizontal', but with a textbox in the middle to enter the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the join table and make an inline:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

```
from django.contrib import admin

class IngredientAmountInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = IngredientAmount

class CocktailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        IngredientAmountInline,
    ]
```